# Image wont load on canvas. canvas.width error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hey my image wont load onto the canvas. I've been at this for hours and I cant figure out what it is. I started to debug my code in google chrome and the console says canvas.width is set to null. Thats the only error I can find.

Here is my code:

```
function gameLoop()
 {

     drawBackground();
     drawPlayer();
 }
 function drawBackground()
 {
   var img = new Image();   
img.src = "Images/GrassTexture.png";
   g.drawImage(img,0, 0, 500, 500); 
 }
 function drawPlayer()
 {
  var player1 = new Image();   
player1.src = "Images/Players/Mignolet.png";
   g.drawImage(player1,0, 0,50 , 50); 
 }
  setInterval(gameLoop, 1);
   var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 500;
   var g = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

html

```
html>
    <head>
        <title>Football</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/Css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Js/Js.js"></script>
        <div id="Background">
            <div id="Header">
            </div>
        <div id="Wrapper">
       <canvas id="Canvas">
       </canvas>  
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Css

```
#Canvas
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    margin-left: 300px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the script is being called before the html is rendered which is why you were getting the error. its always best to place scripts just before the `<body>` tag ends.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Football</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/Css.css">
</head>
<body>       
    <div id="Background">
        <div id="Header">
        </div>
    <div id="Wrapper">
   <canvas id="Canvas">
   </canvas>  
    </div>
    </div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="Js/Js.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Although that did fix 50 errors im still getting the error cannot set property "width" to null :(

Comment: can you post your html code as well? its possible that `var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");` is not setting the variable `canvas` properly. This could be because the id is wrong.

Comment: unfornuately that isnt the problem  il edit it in now :)